# In what cases are go binaries dynamically linked?

Tags: go, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

One important feature of the Go programming language is that it produces statically linked binaries. However, when I ran `ldd *` in my `$GOPATH/bin`, I found several dynamic executables. Is there a clear set of rules to understand under what circumstances does the go compiler produce dynamically linked binaries?

Comment: What do you mean with *dynamic executables*? Although the produced binary is statically linked, it may still depends on *core system library* e.g. `libc` in POSIX system, `kernel32.dll` in Windows, etc.

Comment: I mean dynamically linked executables. I should have mentioned it clearly.

Comment: Also, running ldd on most golang built binaries gives the output 'not a dynamic executable', so I think not even dependent on libc. But some projects have dynamically linked binaries.

Comment: It depends on the package that is being used by the executable. For example when using `net/http` as in [Get example](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Get), the produced binary depends on `pthread`, `libc`, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [cgo](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/), which is how Go links to C programs, which can of course use dynamically-linked libraries.

Comment: I too initially thought so. However, I searched in one of the projects (gocode) for 'import "C" statements, but couldn't find any. But the gocde binary is dynamically linked.

Comment: @enitihas, just because a package doesn't use cgo, doesn't mean its dependencies don't. Even the std library may use cgo, like in the `net` package, `os/user`, or `crypto/tls`.

Comment: @JimB Is it possible to create statically linked binaries with go even when using such packages from the stdlib?

Comment: @enitihas, yes, sometimes, on some OSes. In some cases you can statically link using cgo too. You have to show exactly what you're tying to do.

Comment: Cross-compiling Linux binaries on Windows delivers static binaries, as does building with `CGO_ENABLED=0`.

Comment: @Adrian, while it takes some extra setup, you can cross-compile with cgo

Answer (score 1):

Go 1.8 has introduced something called Go Plugin which seems to be using dynamic linking.

https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/